# SQL query in Rails using % and LIKE

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to execute a SQL query in my rails app. The following executes normally since it is looking for an exact match:

```
connection.query("SELECT * 
                  FROM test
                  WHERE y=#{connection.quote(name)}
                  ORDER BY x ASC")
```

I want to use the LIKE operator to find partial matches. In SQL it would look like:

`SELECT * FROM test WHERE y LIKE '%John%' ORDER BY x ASC`

How do I do this in my Ruby query? I tried adding `%` in a few places but it doesn't work. I get errors that say my query is looking for `%'John'%` instead of `'%John%'`

```
connection.query("SELECT * 
                  FROM test
                  WHERE y LIKE #{%connection.quote(name)%}
                  ORDER BY x ASC")
```

Comment: @spickermann I appreciate you flagging this but to me it doesn't seem like the same query structure. By reading the post you flagged, it makes me think that I may be writing my query incorrectly or, maybe more aptly, insecurely. Would you be able to re-open this question or explain to me how I can apply the answer you referenced to my situation of concatenating strings as to remove the extra `'` (apostrophe) - Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `%`s in Ruby before quoting:

```
connection.query("SELECT * 
                  FROM test
                  WHERE y LIKE #{connection.quote('%' + name + '%')}
                  ORDER BY x ASC")
```

`connection.quote` will add single quotes to produce a valid SQL string literal and you want to get the `%`s *inside* that string literal, hence the Ruby string concatenation *before* `connection.quote` is called.

Or you could do it in SQL:

```
connection.query("SELECT * 
                  FROM test
                  WHERE y LIKE '%' || #{connection.quote(name)} || '%'
                  ORDER BY x ASC")
```

`||` is the standard SQL string concatenation operator, you might need to use the `concat` function or something else if you're using a database that doesn't really support SQL.

You're better off using the ActiveRecord interface as [spickermann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31353456/479863) suggests but sometimes you need to do it by hand so it is useful to know how.

Answer (score 6):

Since you use Rails anyway I suggest using [ActiveRecord's query interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) instead of plain SQL.

With `ActiveRecord` the query could be written like this:

```
Test.where("y LIKE ?", "%#{name}%").order(:x)
```

You need to have an `ActiveRecord` model named `Test` that is configured to use a database table named `test` (Rails default naming would be `tests`) to make this work:

```
# in app/models/test.rb
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'test'
end
```

Comment: I really appreciate you answering my question. What are the security differences with using ActiveRecord over a straight query as I was using? Or are there other reasons to use ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
connection.query("SELECT * 
                  FROM test
                  WHERE y LIKE '%#{connection.quote(name)}%'
                  ORDER BY x ASC")
```

Keep in mind that Ruby variable interpolation just replaces #{foo} with the value of `foo`, no more, no less.  When you add the extra % inside the brackets, you are asking Ruby to evaluate `%foo%`, which is not a valid Ruby variable.

Comment: This is being evaluated as `'%'John'%'` and throwing an error